# How can I use ajax push engine to make notifications?

Tags: javascript, ajax, notifications, ape

I have heard about APE (ajax push engine) to make realtime notifications but I want to use the javascript framework of the APE instead of installing it.

Can any one help me with how to implement it for a realtime notification?
As far as I understand, Ajax Push Engine puts less load on server so I would like to use it for the realtime system. thanks.

Comment: did you try anything yet? something like Google you know: http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Getting_Started

Comment: have gone through that but still i would like to know if some gud tutorial exist so that i could make my notification system realtime.

Comment: i know it's not what you are asking for but, if you want realtime, you should really have a look at http://www.xrtml.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do "real time" applications with APE, you must install the APE Server. You can't do push in simple HTTP.
If you don't have access to your server or don't want to install anything, try some services like Pusher.